# Georgia visa application in the UK on South African passport

Tags: georgia-country, south-african-citizens

Can I apply for a visa for Georgia while in the UK on a visitor visa for 5 months on a South African passport?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. South Africans DO NOT NEED visa for visiting Georgia for up to one year.

Link - [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Georgia](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=956&lang=Eng)

*Or maybe you can, but you don't need to.*

Comment: So would be stamped in upon arrival ? Thanks

Comment: @Dee Correct, Your passport should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay. No additional period of validity beyond this is required.